# Facebook authentication for Django projects

Tags: django, facebook, authentication

Which implementation is most correct, modern and easiest in your opinion:
http://github.com/dickeytk/django_facebook_oauth
or
http://github.com/teebes/django-facebookconnect/
or
http://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook
?

Thanks!

Comment: The ecosystem is even more dense: http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/facebook-authentication/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to that djangopackages grid, and a brief look about, I would have to say:

https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth

Comment: https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth is the best of the lot. Stay away from everything else.